# i need to find the length of the response field value : Expeced length of the field should not be greater than 20. can someone help me in gettin git

Tags: javascript

I need to validate the response field value length.

Lets say there is a field name employee id and the requirement is to find whether the field is displaying only 20 characters and not more than that

```
const responseJson = pm.response.json();

for (var i = 0; i < responseJson.data.length; i++) {
    let defleetDealer = responseJson.data[i].defleetDealer;

    pm.test("defleetDealer length of " + defleetDealer + " is 10", function () {
        pm.expect(defleetDealer).to.have.lengthOf(20);
```

FAILED: and error message is displayed as

> Length as expected | ReferenceError: jsonData is not defined